# C# class uses in classes wht it doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, class, static

I have class for connection to database:

```
namespace DamianWprawka
{
    class SQLcon
    {
        static SqlConnection konekt = new SqlConnection();

        public SQLcon()
        {
            konekt.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;" 
            + "Initial Catalog=PRACA;" + "User id=sa;" + "Password=xxXXxx;";
        }

        void open()
        {
            konekt.Open();
        }

        void close()
        {
            konekt.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And other for query like insert, update, delete, download data itp:

```
   namespace DamianWprawka
   {
        class SQLquery
        {
            SQLcon SQLcnn = new SQLcon();

            public void PobierzPracownik
            {
               SQLcnn.Open();
            }
        }
    }
```

Why can't I call `SQLcnn.Open();`? I try with static field/class and I can only use it normally in Main. I know I can do connection and query in one class but I want understand this mystery for future.

Comment: You should read about [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Comment: Your method is `open`, not `Open`. Your class is also private, not public.

Comment: Two reasons: 1. `void open()` is a `private` function, meaning you cannot access it outside of the class itself. 2. `open()` and `Open()` can be two different functions. C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You should make changes inside ** **

```
class SQLcon
{
    ....
    **public** void open()  ...
    **public** void close()  ...
}

class SQLquerry
{
    ....
    public void PobierzPracownik**()**
    {
       SQLcnn.**open**();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The access modifier and the method for the connection class should be public.  Like this:

```
public class SQLcon
{
       static SqlConnection konekt = new SqlConnection();
       public SQLcon()
       {
           konekt.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;" +  "Initial Catalog=PRACA;" + "User id=sa;" + "Password=xxXXxx;";
    }
   public void open()
    {
        konekt.Open();
    }
   public void close()
    {
        konekt.Close();
    }
}
```

The open() and close() method could also be protected if you want them to be private for all other classes and the Query class inherit the connection class.